# Does non alcoholic beer have roughly the same alcohol as orange juice or a ripe banana contain at .5% alcohol?

Tags: nutrition, beer

On a post on the [beer cartel about](https://www.beercartel.com.au/blog/the-complete-lowdown-on-alcohol-free-beers/) non-alcoholic beer in the post, it implies that non-alcoholic beer has roughly the same level of alcohol as freshly squeezed orange juice or ripe banana

> Alcohol-Free Beer, a.k.a non-alcoholic beer, are brews that have less
>   than 0.5% alcohol by volume (ABV). Amazingly, that’s roughly the same
>   percentage of alcohol found in freshly squeezed orange juice, or a
>   very ripe banana.

Comment: Which are you asking?  0.5% or .05% ??

Comment: @GEdgar .5% also 0.5% as per the claim

Comment: It is worth noting that 0.5% is the upper limit in alcohol for non-alcoholic beer in the US and EU. In the UK, alcohol free beer is 0.05%. So for the UK limit at least this may be true, but the article refers to the higher limit.

Comment: @user1605665: It was edited to correct it, from .05 to .5, good.

Answer (score 9):

Fruit juice and certain bakery products contain a little bit of alcohol. This [study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5421578/) found that the type of orange juice they tested contains 0.77 g/L of alcohol, roughly 0.06% ABV. This [study](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jf00094a029) tested a variety of orange juices and found .0075%-.09% ABV. This is less than a fifth of the amount claimed in the question.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how much alcohol really is found in non alcoholic beer.

Comment: @lalala When I wrote the question, I looked but was unable to find good data for beers that were less than 0.5%. Some non-alcoholic beers meet the legal limit of 0.5%.